# How to check if type is Boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, types

How can I check if a variable's type is of type Boolean?

I mean, there are some alternatives such as:

```
if(jQuery.type(new Boolean()) === jQuery.type(variable))
      //Do something..
```

But that doesn't seem pretty to me.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: Aren't `true` or `false` of type Boolean?

Comment: You don't need to check, you can do this `!!( ... some expression ...)` and the result will be a boolean.

Comment: No: `true` and `false` are primitives of type `boolean`. The capital-B Boolean type is an object wrapper type for boolean primitives.

Comment: @CallumLinington that won't work for objects created with the Boolean constructor :)

Comment: @Pointy what do you mean?

Comment: @CallumLinington try: `if (new Boolean(false)) alert("hi");` - a capital-B Boolean object is always "truthy", regardless of the underlying little-b boolean value.

Comment: The question for type 'string' is [here](/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string-in-javascript "Check if a variable is a string in JavaScript").

Answer (score 814, accepted):

That's what [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is there for. The parentheses are optional since it is an *operator*.

```
if (typeof variable == "boolean") {
    // variable is a boolean
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the OP is trying to do, but capital-B Boolean objects give "object" as their type via `typeof`.

Comment: @Pointy from OP's comment on Satpal's answer(now deleted) asks for what I intepreted I suppose.

Comment: 1) `typeof` is not a function. 2) Using the triple operator === with `typeof` is not required, since it will return always a string (afaik, but as far as I remember, there was another case for some very old browsers). 3) `typeof` and string comparisons are slow. Don't use them. Check directly with `(variable === true || variable === false)` (I suggest to write a function).

Comment: wouldn't `typeof(variable) === typeof(true)` be more robust?

Comment: `var name = true
console.log(typeof(name))
`    why the output is `string` ?

Comment: @TusharNiras `name` is a global window property with a special *getter* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: @Zach Lysobey  true.. resolved long back... thanks anyway

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus @AmitJoki that's nonsense, there is no advantage in using more verbose `typeof true` instead of `"boolean"`. New versions ECMAScript will never have any breaking changes.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus is boolean spelt wit a capital B? In english is it boolean or booleen?

Answer (score 78):

With **pure JavaScript**, you can simply use `typeof` and do something like `typeof false` or `typeof true` and it will return `"boolean"`...

But that's not the only way to do that, I'm creating functions below to show different ways you can check for **Boolean** in JavaScript, also different ways you can do it in some new frameworks, let's start with this one:

```
function isBoolean(val) {
   return val === false || val === true;
}
```

Or one-line **ES6** way ...

```
const isBoolean = val => 'boolean' === typeof val;
```

and call it like!

```
isBoolean(false); //return true
```

Also in **Underscore** source code they check it like this(with the _. at the start of the function name):

```
isBoolean = function(obj) {
   return obj === true || obj === false || toString.call(obj) === '[object Boolean]';
};
```

Also in **jQuery** you can check it like this:

```
jQuery.type(true); //return "boolean"
```

In **React**, if using propTypes, you can check a value to be boolean like this:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};
```

If using **TypeScript**, you can use type **boolean** also:

```
let isDone: boolean = false;
```

Also another way to do it, is like converting the value to boolean and see if it's exactly the same still, something like:

```
const isBoolean = val => !!val === val;
```

or like:

```
const isBoolean = val => Boolean(val) === val;
```

and call it!

```
isBoolean(false); //return true
```

It's not recommended using any framework for this as it's really a simple check in JavaScript.

Comment: Disagree: `new Boolean(true) === new Boolean(true)` should return false (as references are different). That's why the `isBoolean(new Boolean(true))` will say **false** while it must be **true** ( `new Boolean(true)` is of type *boolean*).

Comment: How do you type val?
export const isBoolean = (val: ???): boolean => "boolean" === typeof val

Comment: @FloodGames you can use `unknown`.

Answer (score 47):

If you just want to check for a primitive value:

```
typeof variable === 'boolean'
```

If for some strange reason you have Booleans created with the constructor, those aren't really Booleans but objects containing a primitive Boolean value, and one way to check for both primitive Booleans and objects created with `new Boolean` is to do:

```
function checkBool(bool) {
    return typeof bool === 'boolean' ||
           (typeof bool === 'object' &&
            bool !== null            &&
           typeof bool.valueOf() === 'boolean');
}
```

```js
function checkBool(bool) {
    return typeof bool === 'boolean' ||
           (typeof bool === 'object' &&
            bool !== null            &&
           typeof bool.valueOf() === 'boolean');
}

console.log( checkBool( 'string'          )); // false, string
console.log( checkBool( {test: 'this'}    )); // false, object
console.log( checkBool( null              )); // false, null
console.log( checkBool( undefined         )); // false, undefined
console.log( checkBool( new Boolean(true) )); // true
console.log( checkBool( new Boolean()     )); // true
console.log( checkBool( true              )); // true
console.log( checkBool( false             )); // true
```

Comment: It doesn't seem very practical to me to treat Boolean primitives and Boolean objects as the same, because I can't use them in the same way anyway.

Comment: @FelixKling - doesn't seem very practical to me either, but it seems like the OP is trying to determine if a variable is a boolean, even when created with `new Boolean()`, which techically isn't a boolean, but an object, but still holds a boolean value.

Comment: I think the OP just didn't know that `new Boolean()` returns an object (see comments on question). But whatever :)

Comment: @FelixKling - Just reread the question and comments, and I see now that the OP is basically trying to do `typeof variable === typeof new Boolean()` and probably just want a regular typeof check, but somehow got caught up in some strange jQuery syntax instead.

Comment: Depending on how resilient you want to make your code, if the `bool` param passed in was `null` the `typeof bool === 'object'` would still evaluate and a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueOf' of null` exception would be thrown on the call to `typeof bool.valueOf()`. Thus, I would change that last line to read: `(typeof bool === 'object' && bool && typeof bool.valueOf() === 'boolean');` which will evaluate only when `bool` is *not* null.

Answer (score 26):

There are three "vanilla" ways to check this with or without jQuery.

1. First is to force boolean evaluation by coercion, then check if it's equal to the original value:

   ```
   function isBoolean( n ) {
       return !!n === n;
   }
   ```
2. Doing a simple `typeof` check:

   ```
   function isBoolean( n ) {
       return typeof n === 'boolean';
   }
   ```
3. Doing a completely overkill and unnecessary instantiation of a class wrapper on a primative:

   ```
   function isBoolean( n ) {
       return n instanceof Boolean;
   }
   ```

The third will only return `true` **if** you create a `new Boolean` class and pass that in.

To elaborate on primitives coercion (as shown in #1), all primitives types can be checked in this way:

- **`Boolean`**:

  ```
  function isBoolean( n ) {
      return !!n === n;
  }
  ```
- **`Number`**:

  ```
  function isNumber( n ) {
      return +n === n;
  }
  ```
- **`String`**:

  ```
  function isString( n ) {
      return ''+n === n;
  }
  ```

Comment: Why is type coersion "most optimal"? Is it faster or more readable than `typeof`? I highly doubt it.

Comment: So, in theory, coercing the value to a boolean does 1 coercion + 2 comparisons + 1 comparison. The first two comparisons are during the coercion steps, and the last comparison is against the first position (which is now a primitive).

Doing `typeof` is also 1 coercion, but the `typeof` method does a few getters and comparisons inside + 1 comparison at the very end. [Here's the V8 reference for `typeof`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/e034c1ad9c44b146cd9b4fed54a900b2e4845976/src/compiler/simplified-lowering.cc#L391)

Comment: After all, either method is so damn fast, the nanoseconds amount of difference is so small, it would be hard to even test out which was faster.

Here are two JSPerf's. One says `!!` is faster, one says `Boolean` is faster. Just a reference to how small the delta is between tests. Boolean checks are fast.

https://jsperf.com/bool-not-not
https://jsperf.com/bool-vs-doublenot

Comment: I agree that the difference is not measurable and in such case, readabilidy should AFAIK always go first. Thus the standard and comprehensible `typeof val === "boolean"` is optimal.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Readability is important. Operators aren't as readable - will update

Comment: I think it would not be a problem to use the operators though. If they are wrapped in a function, that still makes it self-explanatory what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 18):

You can use pure JavaScript to achieve this:

```
var test = true;
if (typeof test === 'boolean')
   console.log('test is a boolean!');
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want your function can validate boolean objects too, the most efficient solution must be:

```
function isBoolean(val) {
  return val === false || val === true || val instanceof Boolean;
}
```

Comment: instanceof Boolean is not declared for me.

Answer (score 6):

I would go with Lodash: [isBoolean](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#isBoolean) checks whether the passed-in variable is either primitive boolean or Boolean wrapper object and so accounts for all cases.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to check for true and false is:
`(typeof value === "boolean")`,
but if `value` is an instance of the **`Boolean`** class, then it will return `"object"`.

So to handle that, we must add another condition to check if:

`(value instanceof Boolean)`

**The code snippet:**

```
const value = false;
//const value = new Boolean(10);
//const value = new Boolean("hi");

if((typeof value === "boolean") || (value instanceof Boolean))
    console.log("boolean");
else
    console.log("not boolean");
```

Answer (score 4):

**BENCHMARKING:**

All pretty similar...

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

const boolyah = true;
var t0 = 0;
var t1 = 0;
const loops = 1000000;
var results = { 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0 };

for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {

    t0 = performance.now();
    boolyah === false || boolyah === true;
    t1 = performance.now();
    results['1'] += t1 - t0;

    t0 = performance.now();
    'boolean' === typeof boolyah;
    t1 = performance.now();
    results['2'] += t1 - t0;

    t0 = performance.now();
    !!boolyah === boolyah;
    t1 = performance.now();
    results['3'] += t1 - t0;

    t0 = performance.now();
    Boolean(boolyah) === boolyah;
    t1 = performance.now();
    results['4'] += t1 - t0;
}

console.log(results);

  // RESULTS
  // '0': 135.09559339284897,
  // '1': 136.38034391403198,
  // '2': 136.29421120882034,
  // '3': 135.1228678226471,
  // '4': 135.11531442403793
```

Comment: Updoot for benchmarks! Thanks for adding!

Comment: where is `results[0]` being used?

Comment: @SoldeplataSaketos its an object, not an array

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way to check type of a variable in JavaScript is [the following](http://www.2ality.com/2011/11/improving-typeof.html):

```
var toType = function(obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
}
toType(new Boolean(true)) // returns "boolean"
toType(true); // returns "boolean"
```

The reason for this complication is that `typeof true` returns `"boolean"` while `typeof new Boolean(true)` returns `"object"`.

Comment: Why would you want to return `"boolean"` if the value really is an object? That doesn't seem very practical to me. Boolean objects have to be dealt with differently than Boolean primitives anyway.

Comment: The code isn't clean, pretty, or clear. Note the OP is asking for a "cleaner way to achieve this".

Comment: I agree that the code isn't clean or pretty, but AFAIK there is no pretty and at the same time reliable option in case if both boolean primitives and Boolean objects at the scene.

Comment: This seems like a seriously overkill solution to do something that can be done natively.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that checks the `typeof` for an argument.

```
function isBoolean(value) {
  return typeof value === "boolean";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we need a single way to check it. *typeof* is not working for date, etc. So I made it easy by

```
Date.prototype.getType() { return "date"; }
```

Also for `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, etc. we often need to check the type in a single way...

Comment: Re *"in a single way"*: Do you mean *"in a [simple](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/simple#Adjective) way"*?

Answer (score 1):

Creating functions, like `isBoolean`, which contains the oneliner `typeof v === "boolean"` seems very unhandy in the long term. I am suprised that almost everyone suggest to create your own function. It seems to be the same cancer as extending native prototypes.

- you need to recreate them in every project you are involved in
- other developers might have different habits, or need to check the source of your function to see which impementation of check you use, to know what the weak points of your check are
- you will be fruustrated when you will try to write one liner in the console on the site which doesn't belong to your project

Just memoize `typeof v === "boolean"` and that's all.
Add a template to your IDE to be able to put it by some three letter shortcut and be happy.

Comment: By the way, if performance is very very important, having a function to check for the boolean value took 10% more time in my tests than doing it inline (for-loop 100000000x) on Node.js. But the worst option was `v === true || v === false`, which does 2 verifications in case of `false`. Ranking: (1 - both praticaly the same) `typeof v === 'boolean` and `typeof v === typeof true`, (2) `isBoolean(v)`, (3) `v === true || v === false`.

Comment: I disagree with this wholeheartedly. Different habits are the exact reason why: How often have I experienced bugs because everyone checked things differently? If you have one place to check for a boolean value, that is much preferable IMO to different-style checks all over the codebase. It is also much easier to consistently change the behavior of such a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(['true', 'yes', '1'].includes(single_value)) {
    return  true;   
}
else if(['false', 'no', '0'].includes(single_value)) {
    return  false;  
}
```

if you have a string

Answer (score 1):

- The most readable: `val === false || val === true`.
- Also readable: `typeof variable == typeof true`.
- The shortest, but not readable at all: `!!val === val`.

  Explanation:

  - [!!] The *double exclamation* mark converts the value into a Boolean.
  - [===] The *triple equals* test for strict equality: both the type (Boolean) and the value have to be the same.
  - If the original value is not a Boolean one, it won't pass the triple equals test. If it is a Boolean variable, it will pass the triple equals test (with both type & value).

  Tests:

  - !!5 === 5 // false
  - !!'test' === 'test' // false
  - let val = new Date(); !!val === val // false
  - !!true === true // true
  - !!false === false // true

Answer (score 1):

One more decision with the [ES2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) arrow function:

```
const isBoolean = val => typeof val === 'boolean';
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solution at the is more specific. You can choose which value you want to consider as a Boolean and you can add that in regex. If you need a more general solution and don't want to add a library, then check out the below solution (taken from [Lodash's boolean](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/isBoolean.js)):

```js
function getTag(value) {
  if (value == null) {
    return value === undefined ? '[object Undefined]' : '[object Null]'
  }
  return toString.call(value)
}

function isObjectLike(value) {
  return typeof value === 'object' && value !== null
}

function isBoolean(value) {
  return value === true || value === false ||
    (isObjectLike(value) && getTag(value) == '[object Boolean]')
}
```

**Another solution**

```js
const isBoolean = (val) => {
  const boolValuesRegex = /true|false/; // Add other /true|false|1|0|on|off/
  if (val === undefined || val === null) return false;
  return boolValuesRegex.test(val.toString().toLowerCase());
}

const values = [true, false, 'true', 'false', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'sampletext', 1, undefined, null, (() => {}), {}, []];
document.body.innerHTML = values.map(x => `${x} - ${isBoolean(x)}`).join('</br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), by using [node-boolify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-boolify), we can use isBoolean();

```
        var isBoolean = require('node-boolify').isBoolean;
        isBoolean(true); //true
        isBoolean('true'); //true
        isBoolean('TRUE'); //false
        isBoolean(1); //true
        isBoolean(2); //false
        isBoolean(false); //true
        isBoolean('false'); //true
        isBoolean('FALSE'); //false
        isBoolean(0); //true
        isBoolean(null); //false
        isBoolean(undefined); //false
        isBoolean(); //false
        isBoolean(''); //false
```

Comment: Is boolean return true only if value is boolean value