# How to return boolean true/false in javascript for an unknown type variable's value?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Its easier to identify boolean true/false if we know what type of variable it is, And in javascript we can use **Boolean** object to check it, Boolean works mostly but **it doesn't reflect for an empty array or object**, Is there any function in javascript to check boolean for a variable where that variable could contains any value like a number, string, boolean, array or object? For now I wrote a simple function sharing as answer also considering any simple solution.

Thanks

Comment: `typeof myVar === 'boolean'` works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if type is Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814585/how-to-check-if-type-is-boolean)

Comment: Sorry that question title was confusing, I've updated the question title. So purpose is not to check the variable type but to return true/false for the value of the variable.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the rules are for when a value, that is not a Boolean, should return true or false. [There are clearly defined rules for when `Boolean()` returns true or false.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean). You've made some decisions in your answer that are not enumerated in your question, which means no one else could possibly answer it "correctly".

Comment: Boolean returns true for an empty array or an empty object, Having said that If the variable is array and it is empty Boolean still returns true where most of the cases we expect it to return false, same goes for an empty object.

Comment: You're re-writing the rules of what's "truthy" and what's not with what you're attempting to do. Are you sure that you (or the next dev) won't get bitten by this?

Answer (score 0):

//Function to check boolean for a variable -

```
function bool(myVar){
    //check the variable type as js considers array as object
    let varType = typeof myVar

    //check if it is true object
    if(varType != 'object') return Boolean(myVar)

    if(Array.isArray(myVar)) return Boolean(myVar.length)

    for(var key in myVar) {
        if(myVar.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return true
    }
    return false    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should work most of the cases

```
var data= [],{},string, bool;

 !!(data && data.length>0 || data && Object.keys(data).length>0 || data===true)
```

more short answer. Object keys also take care array and string.

```
!!(data && Object.keys(data).length>0 || data===true)
```